# Why is xlsxwriter writing like this?

Tags: python, gnupg

Here's my code:

```
#Create the workbook and add a worksheet
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Keys.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
datalist = []
public_keys = gpg.list_keys()
for key in public_keys:
    expires = key["expires"]
    uid = key["uids"]
    keyid = key["keyid"]
    datalist.append([expires, uid, keyid])

for row_num, row_data in enumerate(datalist):
    for col_num, col_data in enumerate(row_data):
        worksheet.write_row(row_num, col_num, col_data)

workbook.close()
```

So when I go to look at the Keys.xlsx file, it kind of half-works.  Column 1 shows a '1', but should show the expiration date in epoch time.  I can confirm that all expiration epoch times begin with a '1'.  Column 2 shows the keys UID.  Column 3 SHOULD show the keys ID in a single cell, but instead it breaks up the ID, and puts a single character of the ID into the next cells.

So kind of like this:

```
A1  B1       C1  D1  E1  F1  G1  H1
1  Keyname   A   2   H   M   7   W  etc. etc.
```

What's goin' on here?  This is using the gnupg module in python 3.  Thanks!

Comment: `write_row` looks suspicious for when you appear to want to write a single cell, not a row.

Comment: What is the console output of the program when you add `print(repr(row_data))` directly above `for col_num, col_data in enumerate(row_data):`?

Comment: mkrieger - I don't want to write in a single cell, though.  I have 3 columns of data, 1 row for each PGP key.

Comment: But within a loop over columns you do want to write one cell per column. If you want to write one line at once, you don't need a loop over the columns. What is the output of the print I mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: I agree with @mkrieger that the `write_row()` in the inner loop doesn't look right. Either way it will be difficult to help you without some sample dat. Could you add some sample data for `datalist` to your example with the associated types shown.